# history.push() changes the url but the upon logging window.location.href, those changes are not reflected

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am looking for a use case where I update the URL by history.push() and render something conditionally if the URL has a specific id appended to the URL. The history.push() changes my URL but upon doing window.location.href , it still shows the old URL. I searched for some solutions but could not find anything.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does **window.location.href** show the same old URL even when you refresh the page?

Comment: yes it does. I was probably using the wrong approach then, I wrapped the complete app in the router and used the history prop from the root component, it worked fine in the end